# Fontawesome Bootsrap Icon Link removing the style decoration

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Hi fellas I have the following basic question but can't get to solve it.

`<a href="#download" class="noStyle"><i class="icon-cloud-download" style="font-size: 112px;"></i></a>`

I have tried to hide all formatting by doing so in CSS but still cant remove styling

```
    a i {
    text-decoration: none; 
}

a.noClass.i:link {text-decoration:none;}    /* unvisited link */
a.noClass.i:visited {text-decoration:none;} /* visited link */
a.noClass.i:hover {text-decoration:none;}   /* mouse over link */
a.noClass.i:active {text-decoration:none;}  /* selected link */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `a.noClass:link i` instead of `a.noClass.i:link` etc. Your CSS-selector is now selecting an `a` element with class `noClass` AND `i`.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `noStyle` in your HTML but you're naming it `noClass` in your stylesheet..